# Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed in the table "Issues"

Tags: mysql, sql, database-design, foreign-keys, create-table

These are the two tables that I have created, but I get an error in the table `issues`:

[image]

I have searched up the internet but was unable to find any solution. Can you please help me in this.

```
CREATE TABLE Issues
(
    id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    title VARCHAR(100),
    description TEXT,
    type VARCHAR(50),
    priority VARCHAR(50),
    status VARCHAR(50),
    assigned_to INT,
    created_by INT,
    created DATETIME,
    updated DATETIME,

    FOREIGN KEY (assigned_to, created_by) REFERENCES Users(id, id)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE Users
(
    id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    firstname VARCHAR(30),
    lastname VARCHAR(30),
    password VARCHAR(30),
    email VARCHAR(30),
    date_joined DATETIME
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

Comment: Most likely, you just need to create `Users` first - before `Issues` - so that the FK constraint can be set and reference an **existing** table ....

Comment: @marc_s, i have tried it that too... but still i am getting the error: ERROR 1822 (HY000) at line 13: Failed to add the foreign key constraint. Missing index for constraint 'Issues_ibfk_1' in the referenced table 'Users'

Comment: Do you really want to create a **compound** foreign key?? There's no matching compound primary key in `Users` .... or did you want to create a FK for `assigned_to` to `Users.id` and another FK constraint for `created_by` - again to `Users.id` - separately?  -----> see @GMB 's answer - he must have read my mind and put it into an answer ;-)

Answer (score 4):

You want two foreign keys, not one - and you need to create the parent table before the child table:

```
-- parent table
create table users (
    id int auto_increment primary key,
    firstname varchar(30),
    lastname varchar(30),
    password varchar(30),
    email varchar(30),
    date_joined datetime
) engine=innodb;

-- child table
create table issues (
    id int auto_increment primary key,
    title varchar(100),
    description text,
    type varchar(50),
    priority varchar(50),
    status varchar(50),
    assigned_to int,
    created_by int,
    created datetime,
    updated datetime,
    foreign key (assigned_to) references users(id),  -- first FK
    foreign key (created_by)  references users(id)   -- second FK
) engine=innodb;
```

Comment: To elaborate: In order to create a foreign key in InnoDB, you need to reference an index in the exact same order. You don't have an index ```(id, id)```, you have a single index ```id```, so you need to use 2 separate FK's to reference this. See the [MySQL doc on FKs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html).